# Implementing Type SB riscv instruction in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, riscv, bitset

I am having some issues, I have made an attempt at decoding a 32 bit binary to a type SB instruction in RISCV Architecture set

I have shifted the opcode, imm, rs1,rs2 and rd values but have not managed to get the correct IMM values

For example for the following 32 bit binary

11111110000001111001101011100011

the immediate value is -12, however in my implementation

```
int type_sb_imm(unsigned char* p) {
    // Extract the 32-bit instruction from the byte array
    unsigned int opcode = (((unsigned int)p[0]) << 24) |
                          (((unsigned int)p[1]) << 16) |
                          (((unsigned int)p[2]) << 8) |
                          ((unsigned int)p[3]);

    // Extract the immediate value from the instruction (Type SB: branch)
    unsigned int uimm = ((opcode >> 7) & 0x1F) |            // imm[4:1]
                        ((opcode >> 20) & (0x7F << 5)) |    // imm[11:5]
                        ((opcode << 4) & (1 << 11)) |       // imm[12]
                        ((opcode << 19) & (0x1F << 12));    // imm[10:5]

    // Sign-extend the immediate value to 32 bits
    int imm = uimm;
    if (imm & 0x1000) {
        imm |= 0xFFFFE000;
    }

    return imm;
}
```

The immediate value returned is 4085, I am wondering where did I go wrong?

Please, modify my function with the correct shifts to extract the immediate value from a 32 bit binary.

Comment: I think riscv is little-endian but you're assembling the 32 bit word as if it were big-endian?

Comment: Yes this is due to my implementation

Comment: I read an extract it from a big endian binary.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying, but `((opcode << 19) & (0x1F << 12))` will always be `0`... Perhaps the shifting and masking needs more attention...

Comment: Do you mind helping me out a bit.

Comment: My advice is to set this task aside and develop the skills to "mask n bits of a byte", then "shift those bits m positions right or left", then examine the results. Then, go on to take two "regions" from the byte and shift those around. It seems you're trying for something that requires more familiarity than you've yet developed. No shortcuts... (For instance, `0x7F << 5` is the same as `0xFE0`. This is knowledge.)

Comment: This issue is I am running a tight deadline, and I am struggling, have been grinding this for days, please if you can assist me it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. From https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/su18_lec/Lecture7.pdf (page 8), the SB format has `imm` in only _two_ places: bits 10:5 at abs bits 31:25 and bits 4:1 at abs bits 11:7. This doesn't match your shifting (which takes bits from 4 places?). As [I think] Fe2O3 suggested, you should create some inline functions that do bit shifting and masking. Call them with (e.g.) `imm = bitmask(opcode,31,25,5) | bitmask(opcode,11,7,0);`

Comment: While I feel your pain (having been in over my head and struggling enough times), there's no getting 'round building one's own foundational skillset. Take a breather, think about "masking one set of bits that I want and shifting those somewhere I want." It appears you're trying to do it all on the fly, and the "luckless" results are meaningless to you. Break it down into tiny pieces and solve one. As @CraigEstey suggests, once you've solved one, you can use the technique to solve more. And, always use Hex... Decimal values are too difficult to think about in Assembler.

Answer (score 1):

Prefaced by the top comments ...

Create a function that uses the table defined bits (e.g.):

```
imm = bitmask(opcode,31,25,5) | bitmask(opcode,11,7,0);
```

Here is some sample code that I did quickly (because of your time pressure). I ran it under `gdb` and I *think* I got the `mask` generation correct--but no guarantees:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;

u32
bitmask(u32 opc,u32 bhi,u32 blo,u32 shfl)
{
    u32 val = opc >> blo;
    u32 mask = 0xFFFFFFFF >> 31 - (bhi - blo);
    val &= mask;
    val <<= shfl;
    return val;
}

int
main(void)
{

    u32 opc = 0xF0FFFF0A;
    u32 imm = 0;
    imm |= bitmask(opc,31,25,5);
    imm |= bitmask(opc,11,7,0);
    printf("%8.8X/%u\n",imm,imm);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you make the function `inline` and only pass constant bit values and shift, the compiler optimizer will generate efficient code.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Will this return the immediate values with the signs? –
> HyperCoderSuperion

No, `bitmask` is *deliberately* unsigned so you can use it on many inst formats to get bit fields.

You can apply the code you already have to apply the signedness.

I'm doing this *too* fast. Here's my attempt, but it could easily be wrong--adjust to suit:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;

u32
bitmask(u32 opc,u32 bhi,u32 blo,u32 shfl)
{
    u32 val = opc >> blo;
    u32 mask = 0xFFFFFFFF >> 31 - (bhi - blo);
    val &= mask;
    val <<= shfl;
    return val;
}

int
main(void)
{

    u32 opc = 0xF0FFFF0A;

    u32 uimm = 0;
    uimm |= bitmask(opc,31,25,5);
    uimm |= bitmask(opc,11,7,0);

    printf("uimm=%8.8X/%u\n",uimm,uimm);

    int imm;
    if (uimm & 0x1000) {
        imm = uimm & 0xFFF;
        imm = -imm;
    }
    else
        imm = uimm;
    printf("imm=%8.8X/%d\n",imm,imm);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> I still don't understand, how do I pass in my instruction array that contains the instructions themselves? –
> HyperCoderSuperion

You've already got most of it in your existing code. After you get `opcode`, just replace your bit shifting code with the code I put into `main`. That is, use `bitmask` instead of the shifts you were doing.

Here's a quick hackup of your code.

**Note:** I used a different way to get `imm` from `uimm` in the second example. You'll have to experiment as to which way (yours or mine) is actually correct because I didn't have time to test much.

```
int
type_sb_imm(unsigned char *p)
{
    // Extract the 32-bit instruction from the byte array
    unsigned int opcode = (((unsigned int) p[0]) << 24) | (((unsigned int) p[1]) << 16) | (((unsigned int) p[2]) << 8) | ((unsigned int) p[3]);

    // Extract the immediate value from the instruction (Type SB: branch)
    u32 uimm = 0;
    uimm |= bitmask(opcode,31,25,5);
    uimm |= bitmask(opcode,11,7,0);

    // Sign-extend the immediate value to 32 bits
    int imm = uimm;

    if (imm & 0x1000) {
        imm |= 0xFFFFE000;
    }

    return imm;
}
```

Comment: Will this return the immediate values with the signs?

Comment: I am just wondering how do i exactly execuete this on my end?

Since my parameter is an array containing instructions.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time out to help me Craig, you have no idea how much this means to me.

Comment: I still don't understand, how do I pass in my instruction  array that contains the instructions  themselves?

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem, the issue is I am passing in an Instruction array that contains my instruction, it would be better if you could modify my function with the correct shifts

Comment: @HyperCoderSuperion I did a quick hack of your code--see my 2nd update.

Comment: What is opc?

do you mean opcode?

Comment: @HyperCoderSuperion Yes, `opc` is `opcode`. In my code, I used `opc` [shorter because I was originally going to post it in a comment instead of an answer--for speed]. I've updated the code to use `opcode`.

Comment: Unfortunately the code still gives the wrong immediate value for instruction 

11111110000001111001101011100011

It is suppose to be -12

https://luplab.gitlab.io/rvcodecjs/#q=11111110000001111001101011100011&abi=false&isa=AUTO

Your code gives 4085

You can verify here