# Verifying my interpretation of LBU,SB and LW riscv

Tags: c, riscv

I have written some code that emulates some instructions in RISCV architecture

Particularly, I am focused on LW, load word and SB, Stored Byte

Here is the schema for them

[image]

Here is my LBU

```
void lbu(unsigned char* instruction){
    int rd = get_register_to_store_into(instruction,21,25);
    int imm = extract_typeI_imm(instruction);
    int rs1 = get_register_to_store_into(instruction,13,17);
    int index = registers[rs1];
    unsigned int value = blob.memory[index + imm];
    value = (value << 24) >> 24;
    registers[rd] = value;
 
}
```

In this method, I am suppose to load a byte from my memory array(blob.memory) and then store it into my int register[32], the issue is since, my register takes 4 bytes per value,

I must **shift the byte in memory, to be of size 32 bits**, I have done a shift operation to achieve this, but I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: What do all the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in your code mean?

Comment: Assuming an `unsigned int` is 32 bits your shift will work fine. But why not simply do `value = value & 0xff;`

Comment: OT: `get_register_to_store_into` is kind of a "funny" name as the function is also used for registers that will be read. Perhaps use a more generic name like `decode_register`

Comment: Looks fine to me. You could also write `value = value & 0xff;`. If `blob.memory` is unsigned then you don't even need that.

Comment: Where do you get the number pairs 21,25.  I read  it as 7,11 for `rd`  Same for the `rs1`, you have 13,17 but I have 15,19.  It's like you're extracting the bytes of the instruction big endian.  RISC V always encodes instructions as little endian even if the processor is in a big endian configuration.  Converting to big endian means you have to convert all the standard, well-documented bit positions, seems pointless and error prone.

Comment: C doesn't do any arithmetic in byte size, a byte operand such as `b[i]`, where `unsigned char *b` (or `uint9_t *b`) is automatically and immediately converted to `int` after the array indexing, so you don't really need any shifting at all.  Since the byte array had unsigned elements, the automatic conversion will be of the zero extending 
 form.

Comment: Aside from the function name `get_register_to_store_into` being odd as already noted above, it is also on a different level of abstraction than `extract_typeI_imm`.  Suggest having `get_rs1()` and `get_rd()` instead that would be a better level of abstraction and would prevent you from having to supply bit positions throughout your code, confining them to two or three functions and not repeated anywhere.

Comment: This is somewhere around the 4th question involving RISC V instructions coming from memory as bytes, being assembled big endian, and then having to use reversed bit numbers for the various instruction fields.  Why?  Are you all in the same class?  Who is telling you to use big endian?  RISC V is little endian for the most part but even if the processor is in a big endian mode, the instructions are encode little endian.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to define some reusable functions that do the low level work.

From your previous [now deleted :-(] question: [Implementing Type SB riscv instruction in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75852140/5382650) I had a [broken] solution, which I've now fixed.

You wanted a B type instruction decode but said SB, so I decoded for SB.

You can adapt this for other instruction formats.

Note that in other questions, others have mentioned that *instructions* are *always* encoded as *little-endian* (and *not* big-endian as you *might* have for data).

The following assumes that you have the *instruction* in an unsigned 32 bit integer. From your newer question, there are functions to get that: [Storing in little or big endian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75861586/5382650)

---

It helps to have a list of formats.

From: https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf on page 12:
[image]

---

From [your link]: https://luplab.gitlab.io/rvcodecjs/#q=11111110000001111001101011100011&abi=false&isa=AUTO we get (for reference):

```
Assembly = bne x15, x0, -12
Binary = 1111 1110 0000 0111 1001 1010 1110 0011
Hexadecimal = 0xfe079ae3
Format = B-type
Instruction set = RV32I
```

---

Here is the refactored code for decoding a B type instruction:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t u32;

enum {
    Rtype,
    Itype,
    Stype,
    Btype,
    Utype,
    Jtype
};

#define dbgshow(_lvl,_sym,_reason) \
    do { \
        _sym = dbgdummy(_sym); \
        if (DEBUG >= _lvl) \
            _dbgshow(_sym,#_sym " -- " _reason,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__); \
    } while (0)

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_sym...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

#ifndef DEBUG
#define DEBUG 0
#endif

u32
dbgdummy(u32 val)
{
    return val;
}

void
_dbgshow(u32 val,const char *reason,const char *fnc,int lno)
{
    char buf[100];

    printf(" %12u",val);
    printf(" %12d",(signed) val);
    printf(" %8.8X",val);

    int outoff = 0;
    char *bp = buf;
    for (int bitno = 31;  bitno >= 0;  --bitno) {
        u32 bitval = (val >> bitno) & 1;

        bitval += '0';
        *bp++ = bitval;

        if ((outoff % 4) == 3)
            *bp++ = '_';
        ++outoff;
    }
    *--bp = 0;

    printf(" %s",buf);

    printf(" %s",reason);
    printf(" (from %s, line %d)\n",fnc,lno);
}

// rmask -- get right justified mask of wid bits
u32
rmask(u32 wid)
{
    dbgprt("rmask: wid=%u\n",wid);
    u32 mask = ((u32) ~0) >> (32 - wid);
    dbgshow(1,mask,"");
    return mask;
}

// sigextend -- sign extend a number from a given width
int
signextend(u32 uval,u32 wid)
{
    int sval;

    u32 shf = 32 - wid;
    dbgprt("signexend: wid=%u shf=%u\n",wid,shf);

    dbgshow(1,uval,"argument");

    sval = uval;

    // shift sign bit into MSB of int
    sval <<= shf;
    dbgshow(1,sval,"<<=");

    // perform sign extension
    sval >>= shf;
    dbgshow(1,sval,">>=");

    return sval;
}

// bitfield -- isolate and reshift a bit field
u32
bitfield(u32 inst,u32 bhi,u32 blo,u32 shfl)
// inst -- instruction
// bhi -- highest bit number (inclusive)
// blo -- lowest bit number (inclusive)
// shfl -- amount to shift left
{
    u32 wid = (bhi - blo) + 1;
    dbgprt("bitfield: bhi=%u blo=%u shfl=%u wid=%u\n",bhi,blo,shfl,wid);

    // right justify the desired field
    u32 val = inst >> blo;
    dbgshow(1,val,"inst >> blo");

    // get mask to isolate the bits
    u32 mask = rmask(wid);

    // isolate the bits
    val &= mask;
    dbgshow(1,val,"&= mask");

    // shift to final placement
    val <<= shfl;
    dbgshow(1,val,"shfl");

    return val;
}

// Btype
int
Bdecode(u32 inst)
{

    u32 opcode = bitfield(inst,6,0,0);
    dbgshow(0,opcode,"6:0");

    u32 funct3 = bitfield(inst,14,12,0);
    dbgshow(0,funct3,"14:12");

    u32 rs1 = bitfield(inst,19,15,0);
    dbgshow(0,rs1,"19:15");

    u32 rs2 = bitfield(inst,24,20,0);
    dbgshow(0,rs2,"24:20");

    u32 uimm = 0;
    uimm |= bitfield(inst,31,31,12);
    dbgshow(1,uimm,"12");

    uimm |= bitfield(inst,30,25,5);
    dbgshow(1,uimm,"10:5");

    uimm |= bitfield(inst,11,8,1);
    dbgshow(1,uimm,"4:1");

    uimm |= bitfield(inst,7,7,11);
    dbgshow(1,uimm,"11");

    dbgshow(0,uimm,"FINAL");

    int simm = signextend(uimm,12);
    dbgshow(0,simm,"FINAL");

    return simm;
}

int
main(void)
{

    // test basic display
#if DEBUG >= 2
    for (int bitno = 31;  bitno >= 0;  --bitno)
        dbgshow(2,1u << bitno,"1u << bitno");
#endif

    // test basic rmask
#if DEBUG >= 2
    for (int wid = 32;  wid > 0;  --wid)
        rmask(wid);
#endif

    u32 inst = 0xfe079ae3;
    dbgshow(0,inst,"raw instruction");

    int simm = Bdecode(inst);
    dbgshow(0,simm,"FINAL");
    printf("main: simm=%d\n",simm);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
   4261911267    -33056029 FE079AE3 1111_1110_0000_0111_1001_1010_1110_0011 inst -- raw instruction (from main, line 187)
           99           99 00000063 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_0011 opcode -- 6:0 (from Bdecode, line 138)
            1            1 00000001 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001 funct3 -- 14:12 (from Bdecode, line 141)
           15           15 0000000F 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111 rs1 -- 19:15 (from Bdecode, line 144)
            0            0 00000000 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000 rs2 -- 24:20 (from Bdecode, line 147)
         8180         8180 00001FF4 0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_1111_1111_0100 uimm -- FINAL (from Bdecode, line 162)
   4294967284          -12 FFFFFFF4 1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_0100 simm -- FINAL (from Bdecode, line 165)
   4294967284          -12 FFFFFFF4 1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_0100 simm -- FINAL (from main, line 190)
main: simm=-12
```

---

Here is the output [when compiled with `-DDEBUG`]:

```
   4261911267    -33056029 FE079AE3 1111_1110_0000_0111_1001_1010_1110_0011 inst -- raw instruction (from main, line 187)
bitfield: bhi=6 blo=0 shfl=0 wid=7
   4261911267    -33056029 FE079AE3 1111_1110_0000_0111_1001_1010_1110_0011 val -- inst >> blo (from bitfield, line 116)
rmask: wid=7
          127          127 0000007F 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0111_1111 mask --  (from rmask, line 75)
           99           99 00000063 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_0011 val -- &= mask (from bitfield, line 123)
           99           99 00000063 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_0011 val -- shfl (from bitfield, line 127)
           99           99 00000063 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_0011 opcode -- 6:0 (from Bdecode, line 138)
bitfield: bhi=14 blo=12 shfl=0 wid=3
      1040505      1040505 000FE079 0000_0000_0000_1111_1110_0000_0111_1001 val -- inst >> blo (from bitfield, line 116)
rmask: wid=3
            7            7 00000007 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0111 mask --  (from rmask, line 75)
            1            1 00000001 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001 val -- &= mask (from bitfield, line 123)
            1            1 00000001 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001 val -- shfl (from bitfield, line 127)
            1            1 00000001 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001 funct3 -- 14:12 (from Bdecode, line 141)
bitfield: bhi=19 blo=15 shfl=0 wid=5
       130063       130063 0001FC0F 0000_0000_0000_0001_1111_1100_0000_1111 val -- inst >> blo (from bitfield, line 116)
rmask: wid=5
           31           31 0000001F 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_1111 mask --  (from rmask, line 75)
           15           15 0000000F 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111 val -- &= mask (from bitfield, line 123)
           15           15 0000000F 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111 val -- shfl (from bitfield, line 127)
           15           15 0000000F 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111 rs1 -- 19:15 (from Bdecode, line 144)
bitfield: bhi=24 blo=20 shfl=0 wid=5
         4064         4064 00000FE0 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111_1110_0000 val -- inst >> blo (from bitfield, line 116)
rmask: wid=5
           31           31 0000001F 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_1111 mask --  (from rmask, line 75)
            0            0 00000000 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000 val -- &= mask (from bitfield, line 123)
            0            0 00000000 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000 val -- shfl (from bitfield, line 127)
            0            0 00000000 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000 rs2 -- 24:20 (from Bdecode, line 147)
bitfield: bhi=31 blo=31 shfl=12 wid=1
            1            1 00000001 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001 val -- inst >> blo (from bitfield, line 116)
rmask: wid=1
            1            1 00000001 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001 mask --  (from rmask, line 75)
            1            1 00000001 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001 val -- &= mask (from bitfield, line 123)
         4096         4096 00001000 0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_0000_0000_0000 val -- shfl (from bitfield, line 127)
         4096         4096 00001000 0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_0000_0000_0000 uimm -- 12 (from Bdecode, line 151)
bitfield: bhi=30 blo=25 shfl=5 wid=6
          127          127 0000007F 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0111_1111 val -- inst >> blo (from bitfield, line 116)
rmask: wid=6
           63           63 0000003F 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0011_1111 mask --  (from rmask, line 75)
           63           63 0000003F 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0011_1111 val -- &= mask (from bitfield, line 123)
         2016         2016 000007E0 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0111_1110_0000 val -- shfl (from bitfield, line 127)
         6112         6112 000017E0 0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_0111_1110_0000 uimm -- 10:5 (from Bdecode, line 154)
bitfield: bhi=11 blo=8 shfl=1 wid=4
     16648090     16648090 00FE079A 0000_0000_1111_1110_0000_0111_1001_1010 val -- inst >> blo (from bitfield, line 116)
rmask: wid=4
           15           15 0000000F 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111 mask --  (from rmask, line 75)
           10           10 0000000A 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1010 val -- &= mask (from bitfield, line 123)
           20           20 00000014 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_0100 val -- shfl (from bitfield, line 127)
         6132         6132 000017F4 0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_0111_1111_0100 uimm -- 4:1 (from Bdecode, line 157)
bitfield: bhi=7 blo=7 shfl=11 wid=1
     33296181     33296181 01FC0F35 0000_0001_1111_1100_0000_1111_0011_0101 val -- inst >> blo (from bitfield, line 116)
rmask: wid=1
            1            1 00000001 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001 mask --  (from rmask, line 75)
            1            1 00000001 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001 val -- &= mask (from bitfield, line 123)
         2048         2048 00000800 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1000_0000_0000 val -- shfl (from bitfield, line 127)
         8180         8180 00001FF4 0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_1111_1111_0100 uimm -- 11 (from Bdecode, line 160)
         8180         8180 00001FF4 0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_1111_1111_0100 uimm -- FINAL (from Bdecode, line 162)
signexend: wid=12 shf=20
         8180         8180 00001FF4 0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_1111_1111_0100 uval -- argument (from signextend, line 88)
   4282384384    -12582912 FF400000 1111_1111_0100_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000 sval -- <<= (from signextend, line 94)
   4294967284          -12 FFFFFFF4 1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_0100 sval -- >>= (from signextend, line 98)
   4294967284          -12 FFFFFFF4 1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_0100 simm -- FINAL (from Bdecode, line 165)
   4294967284          -12 FFFFFFF4 1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_0100 simm -- FINAL (from main, line 190)
main: simm=-12
```