# Storing in little or big endian

Tags: c, endianness

I am a bit confused whether my two functions are retrieving bytes and storing bytes into a `char` array.

Now, in my system, I store integers into my `char` array (`char *`).

I break them down into chunks of bytes, 4 bytes altogether since we are storing integers.

Are `read_int` and `store_int` little or big endian?

EDIT: Just realized I have been reading it in as big endian all along,

I have altered my code, it is now in little endian

Does it look right?

```
void store_int(unsigned char* arr, int index, int value) {
    arr[index] = value & 0xFF;
    arr[index+1] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+2] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+3] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
}

// Read integer value in little endian byte order
int read_int(const unsigned char* arr, int index) {
    int value = 0;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+3]) << 24;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+2]) << 16;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+1]) << 8;
    value |= ((int)arr[index]);
    return value;
}
```

If it is in big endian, how would I refactor to little endian?

```
void store_int(unsigned char* arr, int index, int value) {
    arr[index] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+3] = value & 0xFF;
}

int read_int(const unsigned char* arr, int index) {
    int value = 0;
    value |= ((int)arr[index]) << 24;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+1]) << 16;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+2]) << 8;
    value |= ((int)arr[index+3]);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: It's big-endian. That means the lowest-indexed bytes hold the most significant bits. Note that the reverse is called _little-endian_, not "small-endian". I would be very surprised if a site like Wikipedia doesn't have a comprehensive article all about this, which might save you from asking.

Comment: One benefit of storing an 8-bit byte at a time in char array (e.g. ASCII text strings) would be that *ENDIANNESS WOULDN'T MATTER*.  Byte order doesn't matter if you're reading an HTML page, for example.  Unfortunately, your code is apparently storing 32-bit ints in a character buffer.  In your case, since the most significant byte is leftmost, the "int" being represented is Big-Endian ("Motorola").  The opposite is Little-Endian ("Intel"), which has the most significant byte at the HIGHEST address.

Comment: It is pointless to help you. You do not listen to the answers.  You shift **signed** integers and it is implementation defined. I have shown you in your previous almost identical question that you **need** to use unsigned numbers.

Comment: `value` and the returned value need to be a `uint32_t`, not an `int`.

Comment: Do not edit your post to "fix" the problems you were asking about, or to radically change the question into something else while there are answers posted. If you have a new question, then post it as a separate new question.

Answer (score 2):

```c
void store_uint32_be( unsigned char *arr, size_t *index, uint32_t value ) {
   arr[ (*index)++ ] = ( value >> 24 ) & 0xFF;
   arr[ (*index)++ ] = ( value >> 16 ) & 0xFF;
   arr[ (*index)++ ] = ( value >>  8 ) & 0xFF;
   arr[ (*index)++ ] = ( value >>  0 ) & 0xFF;
}

void store_uint32_le( unsigned char *arr, size_t *index, uint32_t value ) {
   arr[ (*index)++ ] = ( value >>  0 ) & 0xFF;
   arr[ (*index)++ ] = ( value >>  8 ) & 0xFF;
   arr[ (*index)++ ] = ( value >> 16 ) & 0xFF;
   arr[ (*index)++ ] = ( value >> 24 ) & 0xFF;
}

uint32_t read_uint32_be( const unsigned char *arr, size_t *index ) {
   return
       ( ( ( uint32_t )arr[ (*index)++ ] ) << 24
       | ( ( uint32_t )arr[ (*index)++ ] ) << 16
       | ( ( uint32_t )arr[ (*index)++ ] ) <<  8
       | ( ( uint32_t )arr[ (*index)++ ] ) <<  0
       );
}

uint32_t read_uint32_le( const unsigned char *arr, size_t *index ) {
   return
       ( ( ( uint32_t )arr[ (*index)++ ] ) <<  0
       | ( ( uint32_t )arr[ (*index)++ ] ) <<  8
       | ( ( uint32_t )arr[ (*index)++ ] ) << 16
       | ( ( uint32_t )arr[ (*index)++ ] ) << 24
       );
}
```

Switched to `uint32_t` because `int` might be the wrong size, but more importantly because your approach didn't work for all 32-bit patterns.

Made `index` into a pointer to make the function far more convenient. For example,

```c
char arr[ 12 ];
size_t index = 0
store_uint32_be( arr, &index, value1 );
store_uint32_be( arr, &index, value2 );
store_uint32_be( arr, &index, value3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are storing the most significant bits in the lowest array index, your functions are **big endian**. The `<<24` extracts the **most** significant bits, and then the function assigns them to the lowest index of the array.

To convert them to little endian, you would simply reverse the indices to which you assign the values:

```
#include <stdint.h>
void store_int(unsigned char* arr, int index, uint32_t value) {
    arr[index+3] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+2] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
    arr[index+1] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
    arr[index] = value & 0xFF;
}
uint32_t read_int(const unsigned char* arr, int index) {
    uint32_t value = ((uint32_t)arr[index+3]) << 24; // To make the code more efficient you could initialize value to this directly
    value |= ((uint32_t)arr[index+2]) << 16;
    value |= ((uint32_t)arr[index+1]) << 8;
    value |= ((uint32_t)arr[index]);
    return value;
}
```

**Edit:** Use `uint32_t` instead of `int` as the former is guaranteed to be exactly 32 bits wide, and is unsigned, so there will be funny business.

Comment: Note:`int` is poor choice here! A better type would be `uint32_t` (like ikegami's example above).

Comment: @paulsm4 Answer amended.